# Help with UISearchBar, located in first cell of UITableView? Won't enter searchBar:textDidChange method

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

today I created a tableView, similar to the iPhone Contacts app. I placed a TableView into the first cell, using the code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([indexPath indexAtPosition:0] == 0) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SearchCell";
        UITableViewCell *searchBarCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:searchBarCell.frame];
        [searchBarCell addSubview:searchBar];
        return searchBarCell;
    } // ...
```

The searchBar displays correctly, but when I implemented the search methods, I found that they are not being entered when I type into the searchBar... for example this method:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchTerm
```

I think it is because the searchBar is a subview of another class, the tableView Cell? Thats why the search bar can't access the search methods? I also set the search bar delegate to self, still nothing.

Can any body help?
Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: When you say you set the delegate to self, what is the object self?

Comment: I don't understand. I did this in viewDidLoad; searchBar.delegate = self ...

Comment: Can you post that part of code here?

Comment: do you mean the methods with the search bar? I did searchBar.delegate = self in view did load, how I told already.

Comment: Are none of the delegate methods called?

Comment: none... for sure... I have the
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchTerm

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar

none called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the delegate of your UISearchBar. I read in a comment you did it in other part, but you have to do it after you create the object. I mean after the line:

```
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:searchBarCell.frame];
```

Answer (score 2):

Pls add UISearchBarDelegate like this in .h

```
@interface CategoriesViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>{
```

and in .m put code

```
searchBar.delegate=self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than coding this much you can directly add searchbar in tableview from xib i.e. subview of table. else you can take uisearchbar as searchBar in .h file and you have to assign this searchBar and than delegate searchbar and use all the methods of searchbar as taken in .h file.

Comment: but I don't want to do this through IB... Only programatically

Comment: Some more lines of code will be helpful to solve your problem.

Comment: lines containing what exactly? the methods for handling searches?